# How do i implement the result of a function to a dictwriter in python?

Tags: python, csv

My first function runs smoothly and gives me a list with dictionaries. I want to use this result as an input for the second function.

```
    import csv
    
    namelist = ["Jacob", "Bella", "Edward"]
    def nameinfo(list_of_names):
        returnlist = []
        for names in namelist:
            final = get_all_names(namelist)
            returnlist.append(final)
            return returnlist
        

    nameinfo(namelist)
```

I tried to insert the result as a input to the next function but I get an error message.
I call the result of the first function for namesofthepeople. I tried different but I didnt understand the error message.

```
    namesofthepeople = nameinfo(namelist)

    def write_nameinfo(names, csvfile):
        with open(csvfile, 'w', newline='') as f:
                fieldnames = ['name', 'age','count', 'birthyear']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                #writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerows(names) 

   
        
    

    write_nameinfo(namesofthepeople, "prince.csv")
```

Below is the error I get.

Can anyone help?

```
    Downloads\at3.ipynb Cell 10 in <cell line: 25>()
         20             #writer.writeheader()
         21             writer.writerows(names)    
    ---> 25 write_nameinfo(namesofthepeople, "prince.csv")
    
    Downloads\at3.ipynb Cell 10 in write_nameinfo(names, csvfile)
         19 writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
         20 #writer.writeheader()
    ---> 21 writer.writerows(names)
    
    File c:\Program Files\Python310\lib\csv.py:157, in DictWriter.writerows(self, rowdicts)
        156 def writerows(self, rowdicts):
    --> 157     return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))

    File c:\Program Files\Python310\lib\csv.py:147, in DictWriter._dict_to_list(self, rowdict)
        145 def _dict_to_list(self, rowdict):
        146     if self.extrasaction == "raise":
    --> 147         wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
        148         if wrong_fields:
        149             raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: "
        150                              + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
    
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: `nameinfo` returns a list, which you are then passing to `writerows()`. `writerows()` requires a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) when using `DictWriter`.

Comment: for element in namesofthepeople:
                writer.writerows(element)   

Solved! Thank you Nathaniel!